80s/90s Thriller/Horror - Villain attacks and kills a guy with a mustache, evades police
An english language movie made in the US. Either 1980's or 1990's. Can't remember if the movie was a thriller, or horror film or a both
It involved a guy, who is the villain, with black hair and generally black clothing. 
Story Points:

Edit, added this new story point: The villain attacks the heroes elderly mother, and forces her to call somebody (I think the hero) in order to tell whoever she is calling something. Afterwards, the villain then cuts the phone line and slits the mothers throat with a shaving razor.
One point in the movie, the villain attacks a mustachioed guy in a hall way near an elevator. After the villain brutally beats the guy, he then kicks his victim so hard in the head that it apparently kills him. He then hides and two guys, I think they were policemen (I can't remember), discover the victim, and whilst they are distracted, the villain slips into the elevator.
Now this is the part that makes me wonder if its the same movie. This happens at night btw. During the final part, the villain kidnaps the heroes infant child (I can't remember if he had two children or just one). At this point, the villain looks like he had a beating, and has a somewhat bruised look on his face. He then forces the hero to play a game (I think it was cards) with him. During the final moments of the movie, a huge murder of crows appears and attacks the villain. Now I really can't remember, but the crows either peck him to death and then he falls off the house through a huge hole in the room or they devour him and peck him to the bone.

If any of you know the movie via the points above, please do tell. Thank you very much :)

Sounds like The Dark Half from 1993, that was based on a Stephen King novel.

When Thad Beaumont was a child, he had an operation to remove a tumour from his brain. during the operation, it was discovered that far from being a tumor, the growth was a twin brother of Thad's that never developed. Years later, Thad is a successful author, writing his serious books under his own name, and his pulp money-makers under the pseudonum "George Stark". When blackmailed by someone who has discovered his secret, Thad publically "buries" George Stark. From that point on, Thad increasingly becomes the prime suspect in a series of gruesome murders. 

Pretty sure every scene you mentioned is there, and the killer there murders his victims with a razor. They were sparrows though, not crows, attacking him in the end. Here's the trailer:



