# 80/90s Thriller involving a female killer who apparently kills Amish people and sprinkles gold glitter on the bodies

Tags: identify-this-movie

US made movie. Also, the killer had a catchphrase, but I can't remember what it was. Oh, and she wore a wig.

Story Points

- The intro involves an amish woman arriving in a subway station. She apparently gets lost and sleeps in one of the stations benches. The killer then arrives and finds the woman completely alone and injects her with poisons through a syringe. The killer then sprinkles glitter
- Another scene has the killer kill another amish woman (I think this one has a stocky build) as she is going to her apartment and does the same thing as the woman from the subway station.
- At some point, the protagonists, a male and female detective (the former I think is in his late 40's or 50's) go to an elderly Amish woman's home on the outskirts of the city who apparently has links to the killer. She reveals that the killer was viciously punished by her father for apparently not keeping up with Amish culture and instead went out drinking and partying and wearing not so Amish dresses or such.
- By the end of the movie, it turns out that one of the characters, an anchorwoman, is the killer. The male detective brings her mother onto the studio just as she is about to go live on television. She then breaks down after seeing her (because seeing her reminds her of the torture her father inflicted on her) and she then screams and cries. The mother is shocked and does confirm that it is her. The police then arrest her.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like [Terror on Track 9](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0105568/combined) from 1992, one of several TV movies starring Richard Crenna as lieutenant Frank Janek.

> Lt. Frank Janek investigates the unsolved murder cases in the city of New York. The new challenge is presented to the Central Station. There is a man who likes to kill the girls with a singular method: a drug overdose. Janek investigates with a little jittery because there is a television reporter who goes all out to criticize the work of the police. The case then explodes in his hands when one of the girls is found dead is the daughter of the head of Homicide.

All the female victims have a halo of gold glitter around their heads, and in the end the killer is actually an Amish woman who preferred the big city, and is really the newswoman that hassles the detective. He exposes her on the air and she goes crazy. Here are a few minutes from it:

Comment: @Jackson No problem! Was [this one](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/46273/80s-90s-thriller-horror-villain-attacks-and-kills-a-guy-with-a-mustache-evade/46274#46274) also correct, by any chance?

Comment: @Jackson Cool. (Don't forget to click on the check mark, otherwise it effectively stays 'open'.)